# error while removing node in Binary search tree

Tags: c++, c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am having problem in removing node in BST when the node has both child here is my code for deletion:

```
void remove(int val)
        {
            treeNode *ptr=root,*prev=root;
            if(root->data==val)
            {
                if(root->left==NULL &&root->right==NULL)
                    root=NULL;
                else if(root->left==NULL)
                {
                    root=root->right;
                    delete ptr;
                }
                else if(root->right==NULL)
                {
                    root=root->left;
                    delete ptr;
                }
                else 
                {                   

                    swap(root,root->left);
                    delete root->left;
                    root->left=NULL;

                }
                return;
            }
            else
            {
            while(ptr->data!=val)
                 {
                    prev=ptr;
                    if(val<ptr->data)
                        ptr=ptr->left;
                    else if(val>ptr->data)
                        ptr=ptr->right;
                 }
                if(ptr->left==NULL && ptr->right==NULL)
                {
                    if(prev->left==ptr)
                        prev->left=NULL;
                    else if(prev->right==ptr)
                        prev->right=NULL;
                    delete ptr;
                    ptr=NULL;
                }
                else if(ptr->left==NULL)
                {

                    root=root->right;
                    delete ptr;
                }
                else if(ptr->right==NULL)
                {

                    root=root->left;
                    delete ptr;
                }
                else
                {
                    swap(ptr,ptr->left);
                    delete ptr->left;
                    ptr->left=NULL;

                }
        }
    }
```

Some test cases have been passed successfully such as:

```
3
3 4 5
1 
d 3
```

and

```
5
21 16 78 1 22
2
i 20 d 16
```

But inputs like this makes the program terminate

```
3
3 2 1
1
d 2
```

Complete code can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.com/YvnjD1Pe).

Comment: just a suggestion. why dont you add a `sentinal` root which will never be removed. Now you dont have to check for special cases in your delete code. Would remove around 20 lines of duplicate code. And can you please describe the logic you use for deleting a node with 2 non-Null children?

Comment: can You please answer I am unable to understand how to implement your suggestion

Comment: I think your While Loop Conditions are not correct... It will loop infinite no of times or throws an exception.

Comment: can you please help me fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies within the following lines within the "else"-branch of your remove-method:

```
            else if(ptr->left==NULL)
            {

                root=root->right;
                delete ptr;
            }
            else if(ptr->right==NULL)
            {

                root=root->left;
                delete ptr;
            }
```

Probably you forgot to implement those after copying and pasting from the first case. A quick hack brings me to this:

```
// the node we found has only a single child
else if(ptr->left==NULL || ptr->right==NULL)
{
    // we need to re-add the non-empty sub-tree
    treeNode *partialTree = (ptr->left == NULL) ? ptr->right : ptr->left; 
    // add the sub-tree on the place where ptr was linked
    if (prev->left == ptr)
        prev->left = partialTree;
    else
        prev->right = partialTree;
    delete ptr;
}
```

Comment: what about 2 children case?

Answer (score 0):

Your `remove` function is wrong. In the original code you were always modifying the children pointers of `root` rather than `ptr`. And if a node has 2 children you were not promoting the successor. Read about deletion of BST node which has two children.

Also I have created a sentinal node so that you dont have to check for deletion occurring at root node. Use this constructor

```
#include<limits.h>
binarySearchTree()
{
    root=new treeNode;
    root->data=INT_MAX;
    root->right=NULL;
    root->left=NULL;
}

void remove(int val)
{        
    treeNode *ptr=root,*prev=root;

    while(ptr->data!=val)
    {
            prev=ptr;
            if(val<ptr->data)
                    ptr=ptr->left;
            else if(val>ptr->data)
                    ptr=ptr->right;
    }
    if(ptr->left==NULL && ptr->right==NULL)
    {
        if(prev->left==ptr)
                prev->left=NULL;
        else if(prev->right==ptr)
                prev->right=NULL;
        delete ptr;
        ptr=NULL;
    }
    else if(ptr->left==NULL)
    {
        if(prev->left==ptr)
        {
            prev->left = ptr->right;    
        }
        else
        {
            prev->right = ptr->right;    
        }
        delete ptr;
    }
    else if(ptr->right==NULL)
    {
        if(prev->left==ptr)
        {
            prev->left = ptr->left;    
        }
        else
        {
            prev->right = ptr->left;    
        }
        delete ptr;
    }
    else //two children. Get the right Child's leftmost node (say X) and set ptr->data := X->data. Then delete X
    {
        treeNode* rChild = ptr->right;
        treeNode* rChildParent = ptr;
        while(rChild->left != NULL)
                    {
                        rChildParent=rChild;
                        rChild = rChild->left;
                    }
                    ptr->data=rChild->data;
                    if(rChildParent == ptr)
                    {
                        ptr->right=rChild->right;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rChildParent->left=rChild->right;
                    }
                    delete rChild;         
    }
}
```